# Join two tables to get a third column of specific format

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have Table1 and Table2 in sqlserver. I want the result like in Table3 as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Use an [outer join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx full outer join and a coalesce

Comment: Hi John and DVT. Thank you for your response. I am not an experienced sql writer. Would you mind showing me how the query looks like. Thanks.

Comment: Do `SELECT * FROM Table2` ... do you really see a record which has `C` as a label?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Finally got the result using coalesce.

Comment: Post the query you used, something is fishy about your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query gave me the answer finally:

```
SELECT COALESECE(t1.Label, t2.label) AS label,
       t1.Value AS Table1_Value,
       t2.Value AS Table2_Value
FROM Table_1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t1.Label = t2.Label
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below Query

```
 SELECT COALESCE(T1.LABEL,T2.LABEL) AS LABEL,T1.VALUE,T2.VALUE
 FROM TAB1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN TAB2 T2
 ON T1.LABEL=T2.LABEL
```

Answer (score 0):

Using This query:

```
SELECT t1.Label,
       t1.Value AS Table1_Value,
       t2.Value AS Table2_Value
FROM Table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.Label = t2.Label
```

[image]

Comment: This output would be consistent with the `C` record in `Table2` not having a label.